# Automatic download of top apps from iTunes App Store in iTunes

Tags: macos, mac, ios-appstore, itunes-store

Is there a script or other way to have iTunes download the top (free) apps (in all categories, or specific category) from the app store, like once a week or day?

Comment: Here is a related question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/22424270/129202

Answer (score 1):

## “

> Is there a script... to have iTunes download the top (free) apps (in all categories, or specific category) from the app store, like once a week or day?

## ”

No. But its a really neat idea. And iTunes is [very](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html) very [scriptable](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/).

---

## “

> Is there a... other way to have iTunes download the top (free) apps (in all categories, or specific category) from the app store, like once a week or day?

## ”

Yes, its called [AppleScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript), and it is the language of iTunes [automation](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/).

---

Unfortunately, it appears the #applescript@freenode.irc channel is quite [dead](http://fi.gogloom.com/FreeNode/applescript/Graphic+View) (which says more about irc than AppleScript!), but there are still some great [online](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html) and [offline](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596102111.do) resources available.

I found a very nice [tutorial for beginners](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ultimate-beginners-guide-to-applescript--mac-3436) to get you started.

Comment: After all, I don't think there is enough scriptability within the iTunes application. Do you have a concrete example or is there any other way?